# Problems with deploy ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core) app to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an app on ASP.NET 5 (CoreCLR) and I try to publish it to the Microsoft Azure. I using free `Web App` (not VDS)

I am publishing app using Visual Studio 2015 `Publish->Microsoft Azure`and following [this instructions](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html).

But when I publish it and try to open, I see just non-stop loading of empty page. I enabling logging and view the log (stdout.log) from Azure and there was only:

```
'"dnx.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Also I tried to do `Continiusly publishing` with git. During push, It started restoring packages and failed with error `no disk space available`.

Is there any way to publish ASP.NET 5 app to the Azure Web App?

Comment: Please post the key contents of your repository (e.g. project.json, startup.cs, web.config...) Then we can provide specific help.

Answer (score 5):

## Short Answer

> But when I publish it and try to open, I see just non-stop loading of empty page.

This happens when our app fails to publish the runtime (`dnx.exe`) with the application.

## Discussion

There are several ways to publish ASP.NET Core rc1 apps to an Azure Web App. These include continuous deployment with Git and publishing with Visual Studio. Post your repository's contents for specific help.

The example is an ASP.NET Core rc1 app, deployed to an Azure Web App, via GitHub continuous deployment. These are the vital files.

```
app/
    wwwroot/
        web.config
    project.json
    startup.cs
.deployment           <-- optional: if your app is not in the repo root 
global.json           <-- optional: if you need dnxcore50 support
```

**app/wwwroot/web.config**

Add the `HttpPlatformHandler`. Configure it to forward all requests to a DNX process. In other words, tell the Azure Web app to use DNX.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" 
           path="*" verb="*" 
           modules="httpPlatformHandler" 
           resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform 
         processPath="%DNX_PATH%" 
         arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" 
         stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
         startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**app/project.json**

Include a dependency on the Kestrel server. Set a `web` command that will startup Kestrel. Use `dnx451` as the target framework. See below for the additional work to target `dnxCore50`.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

**app/Startup.cs**

Include the `Configure` method. This one adds an extremely simple response handler.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

namespace WebNotWar
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                    "Hello from a minimal ASP.NET Core rc1 Web App.");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**.deployment** (optional)

If your app is not in the repositories root directory, tell the Azure Web App which directory contains the app.

```
[config]
project =  app/
```

**global.json** (optional)

If you would like to target .NET Core, tell Azure that we want to target it. After adding this file, we can either replace (or complement) the `dnx451` entry in our **project.json** with `dnxCore50`.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
    "runtime": "coreclr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

Comment: Two issues I faced 1) I got a deployment failed error - I was using FREE PRICING TIER, I had to change to BASIC. 2) For MVC projects it is taking some time to load - I am getting a 500 Error with a in memory sql app.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, yes, you can happily run ASP.Net 5 core apps on Azure, but there are some gotchas.

I *don't* know why it doesn't work when you publish from Visual Studio itself (so why is he posting an answer I hear you ask...), but here are some things to have a look at;

- Try running in IIS locally (rather than kestrel) - just to see if there is a problem. For example, you need a Web.config with some settings *or* you need the app.UseIISPlatformHandler in startup.cs.
- Have a look at your `global.json` file. It *shouldn't* matter when you publish from Visual Studio but it won't hurt to set this correctly. You can do something like this:

.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
    "runtime": "coreclr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

**Regarding continous publishing** - that is a known problem with free and shared sites and one that cost me a few hours. Basically, when you are deploying by this mechanism and you specify corecelr, the entire runtime is re-installed from Nuget and that takes up nearly 1GB (the allowance for free and shared sites). Add a few NPM packages and you are over the limit and, hey presto, you can't deploy. @shanselman discussed it recently on one of his podcasts. It's not actually the runtime binaries that take up all the space, but because we are in build mode, all the documentation XML files are installed as well, because Nuget doesn't know you are not in a development environment, and they are huge.
Right now, the simplest answer if you want to use continuous publishing on a *free* or *shared* site is to also include the full runtime in your project.json and set your `global.json` to use the full CLR instead of the coreclr. Just very frustrating.

Comment: We do not need `app.UseIISPlatformHandler` to host in an Azure Web App. I upvoted this helpful answer nonetheless. :)

Comment: Is this still the latest? Have you seen any other discussion about the issue with the runtime installation on free/shared instances? I've been trying to find more information but right now Googling for the right information is difficult since everyone is calling ASP.NET Core five different things.

Also worth mentioning: this also seems to be a problem when trying to build and deploy apps through VS online.

Comment: @aejay: I don't know, but haven't heard anything to say it has been resolved. It's tricky because the root of the problem has to do with how nuget works. It's easy to try though; if your deploy fails, look at the log file and see if it fails during package restore.

Comment: @Frans This is a know issue but not entirely clear if we will need a basic subscription. See the following video at 0:34:40,  [Deploying ASP.NET Core Applications](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B811).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699165/295813) solved the issue.

When creating a new project with the asp.net core template the `global.json` file was part of my API project, but it was also referenced in the Solution Items folder. When published to an Azure API app, two `global.json` files were deployed:

1. In the `/approot/global.json`
2. In the `/approot/src/MyAPI/global.json`

I moved the `global.json` file out of the project folder to the solution root, and re-added a reference back into the Solution Items folder.

When deployed only the `/approot/global.json` file was then deployed, resolving the issue.