# Configuration of ASP.NET Core 1.0 web Kestrel application on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, kestrel-http-server, .net-core

I am trying to deploy aspnetcore application through git on Azure. I've done everything directly as shown in https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

Later on I even follow steps defined in [Problems with deploy ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core) app to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516206/problems-with-deploy-asp-net-5-asp-net-core-app-to-azure) and deployed plain project from https://github.com/bigfont/WebNotWar 
In both cases everything I've got is only a message

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page..

When I try to access any controller the response is

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am pretty sure the deployment itself is fine because I've tried to break a code and it has reacted properly.

Comment: The deployment from WebNotWar is an RC1 application. What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? You can check this via your project.json file.

Comment: I use > 1.0.0-preview2-003121 but I think it does not matter because I've tried to deploy WebNotWar and it does not work either.

Comment: It *might* matter, because the way that Azure integrates with AspNetCore changed after RC1.

Comment: So, basically Azure has changed integration. So why your WebNotWar is still working and my deployment of this (without any changes in code and configuration) failed? I use git deployment that's why I've said that my version of runtime rather doesn't matter but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Azure App Service no longer supports pre-RTM ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/06/14/supporting-asp-net-5-core-rc1-on-azure-app-service/)

> ...ASP.NET 5, Core RC1 or RC2 is no longer supported on Azure App Service. **The only supported ASP.NET Core stack is RTM on Azure App Service.** (emphasis added).

**Existing RC1 apps currently continue to work.** If we deployed an ASP.NET Core RC1 application to an Azure App Service before Azure dropped support, then that application will continue to work and so will its continuous deployment.

## [ASP.NET Core IIS integration has changed](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105)

#### Changes to web.config

[The ASP.NET Core Module](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/aspnet-core-module.html) has replaced the HttpPlatformHandler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    // Use the ASP.NET Core Module
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*"
        modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="..\MySite.exe" arguments="" 
      stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout" />

    // Remove the HTTP Platform Handler
    // <handlers>
    //   <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*"
    //     modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    // </handlers>
    // <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%"
    //   stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### Changes to `Startup`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{    
    // Remove call to app.UseIISPlatformHandler(); 
    // Remove call to app.UseForwardedHeaders(); 
    // Both are handled by UseIISIntegration in Main.
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration() // Replace UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I am a bit confused right now. I am pretty sure that my app is using RTM and it still does not work. Thanks for help, I need to look deeper.

Comment: It's worth posting your web.config file @rylek90. If you'd like, I can augment my answer with a minimal example of an RTM that works in Azure. Let me know.

Comment: That would be great my web.config is exactly the same as WebNotWar's one. Here's my project.json - http://ideone.com/Nk4lbK
I do not have global.json defined

Comment: @rylek90 If the web.config is the exact same as the one in WebNotWar, then that is the problem. I've updated my answer based on this. Let me know whether the change works or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, it appears to work now! It is no perfect, though. It appears that this Kudu tool generates not exactly correct deployment script which does not copy web.config file. What I've done is connect to powershell console and copy web.config to wwwroot manually and magic happens. Thanks, again, for your help!

Comment: @rylek90 To copy the web.config file on deployment *might* require a few things. In your project.json, be sure to include the web.config in the `copyToOutput.include` array and the `publishOptions.include` array. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, will be worth checking. For now, I've just edited Kadu's deploy.cmd.